# How can I read numbers and symbols from one string C++

Tags: string, parsing

I have an input of one string(get it with std::getline(cin, line) where line is std:string line)

```
8 9 + 12 43 - *
```

And I need to get numbers and symbols from this string.

```
8
9
+
12  
43
-
*
```

I'm sorry for such a trivial question. I wrote a lot of bad code and want to know a simple way to do it.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string can be separated by whitespace using splitting.

Check this out:
[Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c)